# Grab a list of rows from a table based on the a cell value

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

How do I grab the list of all rows from a table where one cell is 0.00? 
jQuery code, if possible to do so.

Please no code that loops (no `each` statement). I am trying to avoid looping through.

```
<table id="products">
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Product</td><td>Price</td></tr>
<tr id="1"><td>gdfgdf</td><td>1</td><td aria-describedby="Price">0.00</td></tr>
<tr id="2"><td>gdf455g</td><td>2</td><td aria-describedby="Price">0.00</td></tr>
<tr id="3"><td>gdf43gdf</td><td>1</td><td aria-describedby="Price">6.50</td></tr>
<tr id="4"><td>gdf44g</td><td>2</td><td aria-describedby="Price">7.00</td></tr>
</table>
```

I need to grab the first two rows (in this case) since the price there is 0.00.

Comment: Post some HTML, and we'll tell you ?

Comment: I'll try shooting blind -> `$('table tr:has(td:contains(0.00))')`

Comment: We would be glad to help you if you have some markup and Javascript/jQuery code that you've already tried. What failed or did not work and how can we help?

Comment: Why would `css` matter?

Comment: I need to hide these rows later (so that's where the css comes in). But first I need to grab them. I will re-edit

Comment: Where *only one* cell has text equal to `'0.00'` or where *at least one* cell has text equal to that string?

Answer (score 1):

**Version with .each**

```
    $('td').each(function() {
         if ($(this).text() == 0) {
            $(this).css("background", "yellow");
         }
    });
```

[image]

**Version with :contains (updated to highlight first two rows, not just cells)**

```
var element = $('td:contains(0)');

for (i=0; i<element.length; i++)
{
if (element[i].innerHTML == 0)
$(element[i]).parent().css("background", "yellow");
}
```

[image]

Comment: no each please. I don't want to loop - the whole point is to grab them all w/o looping through.

Comment: @sarsnake no matter what you use it will have a loop in it to check each row.

Comment: @sarsnake Added a version that checks first if the cell contains a 0, that way it won't have to loop "unnecessarily" through other cells like "gdfgdf" "1" and so on.

Comment: @chartlieff, not true. see my answer to this question

Comment: last edit isn't quite right, to check each `td` in row need to filter it from the row using `find` or similar, `$('td')` will get all `td` in page

Comment: @charlietfl Actually, I included the real outputs using print-screen, so they both work, not as elegantly as the .filter() though.

Comment: but consider a table with 10 rows and 10 cells per row, `$('td').each` will loop all 100 cells 10 times. `$(this).find('td')` will only loop cells in the row

Comment: @charlietfl yep, yep, yep, you're right! I can see that, thanks for the correction. I changed it to something more reasonable, but I can't infringe on your answer by using .find() in mine too lol. With the current change made (loop through just once), at least kids will see that there is a long way to do things i.e mine, and there is a shorter way i.e yours&OPs.

Answer (score 1):

Can give you a method that doen't visibly use a loop like `each` but it certainly will use a loop in the background as there is no other way than to loop all the rows to check text.

```
$('#products tr').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('td:last').text() == '0.00';
}).doSomething();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/goucqqtx/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

ok, so it is

```
$("#products td").filter(function () {
                        return $(this).text() == 0;
                   }).closest("tr").hide();
```

This will hide the rows that have at least one cell equal to 0.

Cheers!

Comment: you should look in the jQuery source...will see that `filter()` uses `each`...there is no other way than looping

Comment: Very elegant solutions though! I just learned to .filter(), woohoo!

Comment: @chartlieff, perhaps - but at least I don't have to do it myself now.